# How to Write a plt.scatter(x, y) function in one line where y=function of x

Tags: python, pandas, readability

I was plotting a scatter plot to show null values in dataframe. As you can see the plt.scatter() function is not expressive enough. Relation between list(range(0,1200)) and 'a' is not clear unless you see the previous lines. Can the plt.scatter(x,y) be written in a more explicit way where it could be easily understood how x and y is related. Like if somebody only see the plt.scatter(x,y) , they would understand what it is about.

```
a = []
for i in range(0,1200):
  feature_with_na = [feature for feature in df.columns if df[feature].isnull().sum()>i]
  a.append(len(feature_with_na))
plt.scatter(list(range(0,1200)), a)
```

Comment: Your code is iterating 1200 times  repeating the same operation, the variable `feature_with_na` is a list containing the columns with null values of one particular DataFrame `df` and the number of such columns gets appended in the list `a`

Comment: Thank you @ShivamRoy I just realised the fact. Though I am confused a lot.  Because with this code I got the plot that Allolz showed beneath.probably i did some mistake. i will write the codes and check them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your x axis you have the number, then on the y-axis you want to plot the number of columns in your DataFrame that have more than that number of null values.

Instead of your loop you can count the number of null values within each column and use `numpy.broadcasting`, (`[:, None]`), to compare with an array of your numbers. This allows you to specify an `xarr` of the numbers, then you use that same array in the comparison.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,np.NaN], (100,10)))
```

#### Code

```
# Range of 'x' values to consider
xarr = np.arange(0, 100)

plt.scatter(xarr, (df.isnull().sum().to_numpy()>xarr[:, None]).sum(axis=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. A lot of things to unpack. This is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

ALollz answer is good, but here's a less numpy-heavy alternative if that's your thing:

```py
feature_null_counts = df.isnull().sum()
n_nulls = list(range(100))
features_with_n_nulls = [sum(feature_null_counts > n) for n in n_nulls]
plt.scatter(n_nulls, features_with_n_nulls)
```

Comment: This is helpful, I have figured the difference between my approach and this answer. But seems like numpy broadcasting makes the approach more explicit.